How to change the values of filters of tableau workbooks that are published on the tableau server using python?
I am trying to update the values of single select filters of a view in a workbook that is published on the tableau server.
Using get request from the tableau rest api, i am able to obtain the views and subsequent view id. Using this information how can i update the filter values?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
